# Get the last file name in a S3 folder?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a lot of files in the s3 bucket. The folder/file names are in the following format.

```
s3://bucket/folder/year=1990/1990-01-01.csv
......
s3://bucket/folder/year=2020/2021-01-23.csv
```

How to use Python to get the last file name? In the above example, it is `2021-01-23.csv`.

Comment: How much is "a lot of files"?

Comment: Each day has one file. So there are about 365 * 30 files.

Comment: Can you check with most basic way: `import boto3; s3r = boto3.resource('s3'); print(list(s3r.Bucket('bucket').objects.all())[-1])`?

Comment: Maybe this is the only way. Does it support to search inside a folder? or with some pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this alternative which uses `filter`:

```
import boto3

s3r = boto3.resource('s3')

all_files = list(s3r.Bucket('bucket').objects.filter(Prefix='folder/').all())

print(all_files[-1])
```

It does not do semantic check based on the dates in your files to find the last one. But the example could be extended to do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import glob
import os

# get all csv files recursively inside the folder s3://bucket/folder/
files = glob.glob('s3://bucket/folder/' + '/**/*.csv', recursive=True) 
files.sort() # sort them by name
last_file = files[-1] # get the last element
last_file_name = os.path.basename(last_file) # extract filename from filepath
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't return any file (`files == []`). I tried `s3://bucket/folder/` too. However, `aws s3 ls s3://bucket/folder/ --recursive | tail -n 1` returns value.

Comment: @ca9163d9 I actually tried it now on my linux machine, and it works correctly. maybe you need the full path of your directory. is the `s3` the root directory?

Comment: I see. Maybe because AWS S3 doesn't have real sub-directory.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.